# Doubts about structure padding

Tags: c, structure

Once the extra bytes are added for referencing what will happen to these extra bytes while execution. Are these extra bytes empty or what data will be contained in them?

Any help on this is appriciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: What is an "empty" byte?? You mean like a hole in your memory chip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ISO 9899:2011 6.2.6.1/6
>
> When a value is stored in an object of structure or union type,
> including in a member object, the bytes of the object representation
> that correspond to any padding bytes take unspecified values.

It is unspecified behavior, meaning that the compiler may put any value there, including garbage, as long as it does so consistently for all structs. The compiler doesn't need to document to the user how it treats the padding bytes.

Answer (score 3):

It could be anything.  If you have allocated the structure using `calloc`, then they will be zero initially.  But subsequent operations could result in rubbish being written to them.

Answer (score 1):

Padding is done in structures for alignment of its members. This is done by compiler for optimization purpose so that the access if faster.
You need not worry about the gaps in your structure. Just go ahead and refer/de-refer your structure's members.
One very good article is http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/9705

Comment: Alignment is not necessarily an optimisation feature. Some hardware *requires* a certain alignment for some types that's greater than one.